# Converting dataset to Reward/Miss dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to convert the following dataset (CSV) using **Pandas and NumPy in Python**:

Table 1 (csv)

```
Ads, Impressions, Clicks
Ad_1, 11, 1
Ad_2, 10, 2
```

to

Table 2 (csv)

```
Ad_1, Ad_2
0, 0
0, 0
0, 0
0, 1
0, 0
1, 0
0, 0
0, 0
0, 1
0, 0
0
```

Table 2 has basically impressions as total number of rows with random insertion of 1's (count = Clicks).

The converted table is to run CTR optimization on 2 Ad sets using Upper Confidence Bound algorithm using machine learning. Kindly help how to convert Table 1 to Table 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: It was just to call in more help!

Comment: That's not a legitimate use of tags (let alone that the python/pandas/numpy community is already big enough) - kindly refrain from the practice next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO

TESTDATA = StringIO("""Ads,Impressions,Clicks
Ad_1, 11, 1
Ad_2, 10, 2
    """)

table_1 = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")

def convert(row):
    clicks_to_generate = row['Clicks']
    array_len = row['Impressions']
    ad = np.zeros(array_len)
    ad[:clicks_to_generate] = 1
    np.random.shuffle(ad) # you want it random
    return ad

ads = table_1.apply(convert, axis=1)
series_list = [pd.Series(ad) for ad in ads]
table_2 = pd.DataFrame(series_list).T
table_2 = table_2.add_prefix('Ad_')
print(table_2)

    Ad_0  Ad_1
0    0.0   0.0
1    1.0   0.0
2    0.0   1.0
3    0.0   1.0
4    0.0   0.0
5    0.0   0.0
6    0.0   0.0
7    0.0   0.0
8    0.0   0.0
9    0.0   0.0
10   0.0   NaN

table_2.to_csv('table_2.csv', index=False)
```